# [C]Can I call va_arg with a larger type than the argument, then cast the value?

Tags: c, types, casting, variadic-functions

I wonder if this is valid code:

```
int a(va_list args, int is_int, ...)
{
    long long n = va_arg(args, long long);
    return (is_int ? ((int)n) : n);
}
void b(va_list args)
{
    int x = -100;
    a(args, 1, x);
}
```

I've written some unnecessary complicated code, I've made mistakes, and I feel like this is the simplest way to fix what I did without rewriting the whole thing, but I don't know if this can cause errors(or segfaults, or something else).

Comment: this is called testing your code.... but if I understand you correctly... you didn't test.. and you don't have an error?

Comment: I tested it, and I have no errors, but I know that sometimes, when you try to read something that you're not supposed to read, your code can "work" most of the time even if It's far from being valid or safe, I edited my post, to try to clarify my question.

Comment: You shouldn't do that. The problem is not in the cast but that `va_args` fetched more memory than is was passed to the function. This messes the subsequent calls of `va_args`. I'm afraid you will have to rewrite the parts calling `a()` and passing the appropriate values.

Answer (score 0):

No, and the issue is not just limited to size. If the types mismatch, the behavior of your whole program is undefined. There are some very limited exceptions like signedness mismatch when the actual value passed fits in either signedness.